# How to list out User Constraints in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm looking for an equivalent in PSQL for the below command:

```
SELECT *FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='<Table Name>';
```

I tried `\dt+ <Table Name>` but it doesn't list out the names of all the constraints.

Is there a one line command for this ?

Comment: [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That doesn't list out the NOT NULL constraints

Comment: You didn't mention which ones you specifically want. NOT NULL constraints are stored alongside of the column definition in `pg_attribute`